# How to aggregate this in SQL

Tags: sql

Based on the table structure below, I want to count a value only once per column value.

```
Person ID   Email Template  Email Event
1           A               DELIVER
1           A               OPEN
1           A               OPEN
1           B               CLICK
2           A               DELIVER
2           A               OPEN
3           A               DELIVER
3           C               DELIVER
```

What I would like to is to get number of email delivered, clicked and opened for each person. I am looking to get this number for each person not necessarily for templates. All email templates are delivered just once to a person but they can open and click that template multiple times. I would like to not include the repeat opens and click in this aggregation.

Comment: It was okay when you left the table structure in the post, rather than an image, you can format it to be more readable. Have you tried anything? Is it SQL Server, PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask].  Do not post links to images of data.  Please edit the question.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Before asking question, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I am using bigquery. Thanks for the post suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? I'm not sure what your table is called

```
select t.person_id,
sum(case when t.email_event_type = 'DELIVER' then 1 else 0) deliver_count, 
sum(case when t.email_event_type = 'OPEN' then 1 else 0) open_count, 
sum(case when t.email_event_type = 'CLICK' then 1 else 0) click_count
from <your_table_name> t
group by t.person_id
```